# jQuery .on() not working with PJAX?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, pjax, jquery-on

```
$("#img-switcher").on("switchImageEvent", function(event, triggerID){
    $(this).attr('src',triggerID);
});
$("#page-container").on("click", "img.img-switcher", function() {
    var newSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#img-switcher").trigger("switchImageEvent", [newSRC]);
});
```

This code is not working for me with PJAX it seems. If I initially load a page, it selects the elements just fine and makes the change. However, as soon as I go to another page with PJAX, it will no longer select the element for the .on("click") action. Am I doing something wrong? I tried adding an alert before `var newSRC` to see if it was properly selecting the element with .on(), but it isn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since there is just this bit of code pulled out of context I would assume you are trying to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of using it as [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

With pjax, which uses xhr in order to load elements that have no events attached to them that might be a problem.

So, my recommendation would be to use parent element which is not reloaded and attach event on it. Like this, with topmost, not reloaded element, instead of body:

```
$("body").on("switchImage", "#img-switcher", function(e, src){
  $(this).attr({ 'src': src });
});

$("body").on("click", "img.img-switcher", function() {
    $("#img-switcher").trigger("switchImage", $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Ah ha! Great, thanks! Never thought of that. Accepted answer.

Comment: Also, you may want to edit the first line to function(e,triggerID) to match the rest of my code, for future reference. That was the only edit I had to make to make it work.